# Getting source maps working with evaluated code

Tags: javascript, source-maps

I have a build script that runs all my code through uglifyjs, does a bunch of fancy caching stuff, and ultimately runs `eval( code )` on some JavaScript files.

I'm trying to get this whole process up and running with [source maps](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit?hl=en_US), but I can't seem to get it working as long as I'm using `eval`.  If I link to the files directly using `<script src="...">` it works fine.

In my `eval` code, I have:

```
code, blah blah blah
//@ sourceMappingURL=/cache/618a67795c7460184bd9b99020cbb9fd.map
```

and then in that `.map` file, I have:

```
{
      "version"  : 3
    , "file"     : "618a67795c7460184bd9b99020cbb9fd.map"
    , "sources"  : ["/js/Parallax-JS/js/parallax-2.js"]
    , "names"    : [
          "a"
        , "bunch"
        , "of"
        , "variable"
        , "names"
    ]
    , "mappings" : "... LONG MAP ..."
}
```

I've tried putting `//@ sourceURL=` at the end instead, and that at least gives me the correct file name, but still no readable source.

Any ideas?  Testing in Chrome 25 (dev) and 26 (canary)

Comment: This seems to offer a solution: https://kybernetikos.github.io/jsSandbox/srcmaps/dynamic.html - but I want to state I did not personally try it.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and the solution seem to be using an inlined SourceMaps (DataURL of a SourceMap).

Here is an example:

`eval("blah blah\n//@ sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,...");`

Seems like you can't reference external resources from an eval.

I think you also need to use `sourcesContent` to insert the source code into the SourceMap.

Tested with Chrome 32.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Could you provide a working jsfiddle of this? Thanks

Comment: This isn't working for me. Was this a speculative answer or did you verify that it works?

Comment: This worked for me on Chrome 99.0.4844.74 for MacOS.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a setup using Grunt to compile javascript to single file using uglify with a source map

package.json

```
"src": {
    "js": "src/js"
},
"dest": {
    "js": "bin/js"
}
```

Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.initConfig({
    /**
     * Loading in the package file to read source and destination directories
     */
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
    options: {
        banner: '/* all.min.js <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n',
        sourceMap: '<%= pkg.dest.js %>/all.min.js.map',
        sourceMappingURL: 'all.min.js.map',
        sourceMapRoot: '../../',
        mangle: false
        /*mangle: {
            except: ['jQuery']
        }*/
    },
    js: {
        src: [
            '<%= pkg.src.js %>/**/*.js'
        ],
        dest: '<%= pkg.dest.js %>/all.min.js'
    }
    }
};

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.registerTask('min', ['uglify']);
```

Which creates the following files:

all.min.js

```
/* all.min.js 04-10-2013 */
angular.module("App",[])
//# sourceMappingURL=all.min.js.map
```

all.min.js.map

```
{"version":3,"file":"bin/js/all.min.js","sources":["src/js/App.js"],"names":["angular","module"],"mappings":"AAeAA,QAAQC","sourceRoot":"../../"}
```

Comment: Poster explicitly asked about using source-maps when using `eval`. That means at _runtime_. Your solution deals with generating and linking source-maps at _build-time_, which is a known situation and not what the question is about.