# Performance hit when using --inlineSourceMap with NodeJS in production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, performance, source-maps

Is there a significant performance hit when using the TypeScript compiler option [`--inlineSourceMap`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) in a NodeJS production environment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing that in production.
There is already a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671390/why-inline-source-maps) about that here in stackoverflow regarding sourceMaps.
Though enabling that in your node.js application would double the `js` file size which would be that good in my opinion

Comment: You don't really answer the question, file size is just one aspect of performance, and you could not care about it at all (e.g. it's your backend, and you never serve this file over the network). Moreover, the discussion you linked is pretty old, and people seem to be clueless about the use cases of this feature.